# How to filter query with EXTRACT statement oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, extract

I have this query where I get the difference between the SYSDATE and some date column. I need to add another filter to this query to filter the records where DAY = 0. is it possible?

```
SELECT REQUEST_ID,MIG_STATUS,
 EXTRACT(Day FROM( sysdate - START_DATE ) DAY TO SECOND) as Day,
 EXTRACT(HOUR FROM( sysdate - START_DATE) DAY TO SECOND) as Hour,
 EXTRACT(Minute FROM(sysdate -  START_DATE) DAY TO SECOND) as Minute,
 EXTRACT(SECOND FROM(sysdate - START_DATE) DAY TO SECOND) as Second
 FROM NET_MIG
```

results:

```
T1_ID  DAY   HOUR   MINUTE  SECOND
1      2,817 12     12      8
2      2,817 8      26      32
3      0     1      0       0
3      1     8      26      32
3      0     13     0       0
3      0     0      59      0
3      0     0      59      0
```

need to add filter
where Day = 0

is this the correct approach?

Comment: just to be more clear, as a result I need to get the records where the difference between the dates is less than 1 day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> just to be more clear, as a result I need to get the records where the
>   difference between the dates is less than 1 day.

You can use:

```
SELECT REQUEST_ID,MIG_STATUS
      -- rest of columns
FROM NET_MIG
WHERE START_DATE >= (SYSDATE - 1);
```

If you want records from last `5 minutes` just use:

```
SELECT REQUEST_ID,MIG_STATUS
      -- rest of columns
FROM NET_MIG
WHERE START_DATE >= (SYSDATE - 5 * 1/(24 * 60));
```

The same for `1 hour`:

```
WHERE START_DATE >= (SYSDATE - 1/24);
```

**EDIT:**

As [@a-horse-with-no-name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) in comment you can use `INTERVAL`:

```
WHERE START_DATE >= (SYSDATE - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE)
```

for better readability.

And [@kordirko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2568341/kordirko) comment:

This solution is `SARG-able`. It means it will use index on `START_DATE` if exists any, where `EXTRACT(Day FROM( sysdate - START_DATE ) DAY TO SECOND) = 0` will skip index on that column and enforce full table scan.

Comment: Yes, but I need an option also to get records by hours and minutes. i.e records where the date diff is 5 minutes and the hours is also equals to 0

Comment: I think using a proper interval is much easier to understand, e.g. `sysdate - interval '5' minute` instead of  `sysdate - 5 * 1/(24 * 60)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Of course it is, I started with one day and go this way to be consistent. Will you add own answer or should I update my answer?

Comment: You can also update your answer with an information, that your approach performs better than @Julien Blanchard (subquery with `WHERE day=0`) , because  your solution is able to use indexes, while that one not.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT REQUEST_ID,MIG_STATUS,
    EXTRACT(Day FROM( sysdate - START_DATE ) DAY TO SECOND) as Day,
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM( sysdate - START_DATE) DAY TO SECOND) as Hour,
    EXTRACT(Minute FROM(sysdate -  START_DATE) DAY TO SECOND) as Minute,
    EXTRACT(SECOND FROM(sysdate - START_DATE) DAY TO SECOND) as Second
  FROM NET_MIG)
WHERE Day=0
```

I'm not sure this is the best approach, since you should be using direct date comparisons as much as possible, but this is one way you can re-use your custom fields in a where clause.